# How is 2-CNF SAT is in P, while 3-CNF SAT is in NPC?

Tags: algorithm, np-complete, np

I am really confused why 2-CNF SAT is in P, while 3-CNF SAT is in NPC. I Read CLRS, and I understand how they prove 3-CNF SAT is in NPC. Can't I use the same reducibility from SAT to 2-CNF-SAT to prove 2-CNF-SAT is in NPC. I don't understand why 2-CNF SAT is in P.

Comment: Note that P is a subset of NPC. Proving that 2-CNF SAT is in P proves at the same time that it is in NPC.

Comment: since its in P, its also in NP, thus i have to show its NP hard, for it to be in NPC, so something could be in P and NPC at the same time?
please answer

Comment: Uh, yes, sorry I answered too quickly and mixed NP and NPC :) sorry :) of course it's not NPC. The actual problem in your understanding is that you can't reduce SAT to 2-SAT, the reduction will fail.

Comment: @antti.huima "Note that P is a subset of NPC". This is only true if P=NP. P is a subset of NP, we do not know if it is a subset of NPC.

Comment: @Undreren Yes, you are right. I don't know what I've been thinking in December.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> why 2-CNF SAT is in P

Because there is a polynomial algorithm to solve it.

A rough sketch of a proof:

Note that any clause in 2-CNF is in the form `A => B` where `A` and `B` are either variables or their negation. Therefore, we can tell that this clause says when A is true, it forces B to be true. It also means that B is false forces A to be false. We have to consider that later.

Now, you can take a variable, one by one, and search if it transitively forces itself to be its negative (A => B => C => ... => non A) and vice versa (non A => ... => A). If the first is true, A has to be false; if the second, A is true. If both, the formula is unsatisfiable.

If you don't find any variable that makes the formula unsatisfiable, it is satisfiable.

Note that this "brutal" algorithm is not the actual one using strongly connected components of a graph, which I recommend you to read on. Yet, it is polynomial (the search for one variable is clearly O(N^2), since you force one variable at a time considering O(N) clauses and you consider O(N) variables, which means the algorithm is polynomial). Note that the fact that we have at most two literals in a clause is crucial. If the clauses were `A => B or C` or something, it wouldn't work as good.

Comment: how do you figure this out, i am kinda lost on this, i am just following the book, am i just supose to know this or accept it from the book. I mean if it was given in a test, i would of probably try to prove its NPC, (reduce it from SAT, or 3-CNF-SAT).

if they as me to show its in P, i would be totally lost

Answer (score 3):

The canonical reduction from CNF SAT to 3-CNF SAT is to take a clause like lit_1 OR lit_2 OR ... OR lit_n and replace it with two clauses lit_1 OR lit_2 OR ... OR lit_{floor(n/2)} OR var, lit_{floor(n/2) + 1} OR ... OR lit_n OR NOT var. If you try to crack a clause with three literals this way, you'll get another clause with three literals, so the same proof won't work for 2-CNF SAT (and probably for good reason).